# How to hide Eclipse toolbar in specific perspective

Tags: eclipse, perspective, perspectives

I want to hide the Eclipse Toolbar in the debug perspective but not in the Java perspective. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to the perspective you want to customize.

Then click on `Window->Customize Perspective..` then in the Toolbar visibility tab you can enable or disable the toolbar you want. Thus you can customize **Debug and Java** Perspectives.

Comment: Mention which toolbar you want to hide. As you have low reputation you can upload screenshots [here](http://imgur.com/) and [here](http://postimage.org/) and update the post with these links

Comment: I have solved the problem the problem is that when I deactivate a element from let say run menu, the menu appears not select so I thought that all its element are deactivated but it not. Normally the tree root will be not selected if all its elements are not selected. In eclipse if you deselected one element the root tree will appears not selected.